# Variables declared in function returning undefined in the console

Tags: javascript, html

Variables declared in a function are returning as undefined in the console when I use console.log inside of the function.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <select id="a" onchange="mit()">
            <option></option>
            <option>Chicken</option>
            <option>Gecko</option>
            <option>Crocodile</option>
        </select>
        <select id="b" onchange="mix()">
            <option></option>
            <option>Chicken</option>
            <option>Gecko</option>
            <option>Crocodile</option>
        </select>
    </body>
</html>
```

Javascript

```
function mit() {
}
    
function mix() {
    var i = document.getElementById("a").value
    console.log (i)
    if (i=="chicken") {
        var c = "has wings"
        var d = "feathered"
        var e = "eats vegetables and grains"
        var f = "white, brown or black in color"
        var g = "40-60cm long"
        var h = "produces chicken meat"
    }
    var o = document.getElementById("b").value
    console.log (o)
    if (o=="chicken"){
        var j = "has wings"
        var k = "feathered"
        var l = "eats vegetables and grains"
        var m = "white, brown or black in color"
        var n = "40-60cm long"
        var p = "produces chicken meat"
    }
    console.log (j)
}
```

I tried to put 'j' in console however it returns undefined, I have no idea how to fix this.

Comment: You are checking for "chicken" in your code but the value from the dropdown is "Chicken" with upper "C".

Answer (score 0):

Strings in javascript are case-sensitive

```js
function mit() {}

function mix() {
  var i = document.getElementById("a").value
  console.log(i)
  if (i == "Chicken") {
    var c = "has wings"
    var d = "feathered"
    var e = "eats vegetables and grains"
    var f = "white, brown or black in color"
    var g = "40-60cm long"
    var h = "produces chicken meat"
  }
  var o = document.getElementById("b").value
  console.log(o)
  if (o == "Chicken") {
    var j = "has wings"
    var k = "feathered"
    var l = "eats vegetables and grains"
    var m = "white, brown or black in color"
    var n = "40-60cm long"
    var p = "produces chicken meat"
  }
  console.log(j)
}
```

```html
<select id="a" onchange="mit()">
  <option></option>
  <option>Chicken</option>
  <option>Gecko</option>
  <option>Crocodile</option>
</select>
<select id="b" onchange="mix()">
  <option></option>
  <option>Chicken</option>
  <option>Gecko</option>
  <option>Crocodile</option>
</select>
```